# Render a tab that is hidden (on tab-toggle click)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

For a website i am creating, i would like to show company information in different tabs. One is specific on company information, the second would show Google charts with historic information, the 3rd would show other graphs.

I am using a Bootstrap template that create the different tabs:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a href="#info" data-toggle="tab"><h5>Company information</h5></a></li>
<li><a href="#network" data-toggle="tab"><h5>network</h5></a></li>
<li><a href="#sales" data-toggle="tab"><h5>Sales</h5></a></li>
</ul>
```

Now i have different tabs:

```
<div class="tab-content">
 <div class="tab-pane active" id="info">
 <p>[[company description]]</p>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="network">
<p>[[company network]]</p>
</div>
 </div>
```

I created a Google Chart and pasted this in a hidden tab (div) but this doesn't show up in the correct size. I expect this to have to do with the fact the dimensions of the div are still unclear at render time?

How could i render it, ONLY if the tab is clicked? i use the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart"], callback: init});

  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();


    data.addColumn('number', 'x');
    data.addColumn('number', 'values');
    data.addColumn({id:'i0', type:'number', role:'interval'});
    data.addColumn({id:'i1', type:'number', role:'interval'});
    data.addColumn({id:'i2', type:'number', role:'interval'});
    data.addColumn({id:'i2', type:'number', role:'interval'});
    data.addColumn({id:'i2', type:'number', role:'interval'});
    data.addColumn({id:'i2', type:'number', role:'interval'});

    data.addRows([
        [1, 100, 90, 110, 85, 96, 104, 120],
        [2, 120, 95, 130, 90, 113, 124, 140],
        [3, 130, 105, 140, 100, 117, 133, 139],
        [4, 90, 85, 95, 85, 88, 92, 95],
        [5, 70, 74, 63, 67, 69, 70, 72],
        [6, 30, 39, 22, 21, 28, 34, 40],
        [7, 80, 77, 83, 70, 77, 85, 90],
        [8, 100, 90, 110, 85, 95, 102, 110]]);

    // The intervals data as narrow lines (useful for showing raw source data)
    var options_lines = {
        title: 'Line intervals, default',
        curveType: 'function',
        lineWidth: 4,
        intervals: { 'style':'line' },
        legend: 'none'
    };

    var chart_lines = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_lines'));
    chart_lines.draw(data, options_lines);
```

Thanks in advance,
Robbie

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap's Tab JavaScript component will fire events when showing / hiding tabs. In your case you probably need to add an event listener for the `shown.bs.tab` event. The event listener should render the Google chart if it's run for the first time.

Take a look at the [JavaScript > Tabs > Events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-events) section of Bootstraps documentation for more information